# IRSSI shows Wine in "Unchanged" list in Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: installation, wine, synaptic

I was downloading an IRC Client called **irssi** via the Synaptic Packet Manager but it listed `wine` and `wine1.2` in the `Unchanged` list (of dependencies). I do have `wine` installed.

This suggests to me that `irssi` is dependent on `wine`. What is a Windows-related app doing in an Linux repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IRSSI](http://packages.ubuntu.com/irssi) has no listed dependencies to `wine`, as the packages site confirms. That message indicates that there may be an upgrade awaiting, or if a package has been pinned it's state will not change (since there is no dependency). If you installed wine manually, or have made any modifications to the way it operates within Aptitude you will get that message. Unchanged ultimately indicates that during this process those packages, including `wine`, will not change.

Comment: mhhh I don't quite get it (its 2:15 AM here; maybe that's why)... I half understand what you've said... Do you mean that Synaptic is reporting on something totally unrelated to the particular action I chose; ie. the action of installing *irsssi*. .. If so, it makes sense, but I find it odd that I a being presented with unrequest and unrelated info....  (I'd better come back to this after a night's sleep...

Comment: I've looked a bit more into it, and this `Unchanged` list reports on the **"upgradable state of the system"**, and not only about **"my explicit install actions"** (as I thought it meant)... and I now know what the "Mark All Upgrades" button means; its shows a 3rd list; labeled `To be Upgraded` (which shows exactly what appears in the `Unchanged` list)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's just because there are some Wine updates available, but you have not checked them for an update. Try to run `Update Manager`, maybe you'll find these updates ready to install.

Comment: Maybe my suggestion is the same of Marco?

Comment: It is the same, and it is different because another voice helped drive the message home (so I googled a bit more) ..... From a question about Linux Mint: `... a lot of entries (like linux-generic) are in the unchanged category. at another place the name of this list is: installed (updatable).` ... This "installed (updatable)" label makes more sense to me than "unchanged". I suppose it just comes down to knowing that Synaptic is **also** informing me of `currently available updates` ... Thanks